# Tuning KMeans K paramer - pitfalls and general guidelines

Tags: clustering, k-means

I'm clustering data with true/external labels, call the number of such groups K0 where K0/n is close to 0.01. However I also need to be totally agnostic to the validity of these labels.

Call my argument specification to my cluster algorithm K1. I'm currently measuring performance for a range K1=3,4,5,...,K0,K0+1,...,K0+10.

The performance metrics I'm examining use both information from the external labels and inertia from the model's output (i'm currently using [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)).

- What's an appropriate upper bound for K?
- Are there unintended consequences to incrementing by 2s, 3s, etc to save compute resources? For instance, what if I only tested even K?
- How else can I measure intrinsic goodness-of-fit besides inertia, which seems to be monotonically decreasing as K increases?

Comment: Since k-means is randomized, you should try each k *several* times...

Comment: actually each user's run of scikit's kmeans is the best of 10 random instantiations, by default

Comment: Yes, but you should take all runs into account in order to choose the "best" k, because the stability of results is important, too. Also think about noise, because kmeans is not robust to noise.

Comment: what does high variance (of inertia or SSE) say about the value of K chosen?

Comment: also, can anyone confirm whether the built-in 10x in scikit means you need to call it multiple times, and if so how many times (e.g. another 10x)?

Comment: For your problem it is probably better to use `n_init=1`, and perform a more detailed analysis on *all* these samples to measure stability and significance. You'd expect a good fit to be significantly better than the alternatives.

Comment: thank you - if you submit this as an answer, I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem it is probably better to use `n_init=1`, and perform a more detailed analysis on all these samples to measure stability and significance. You'd expect a good fit to be significantly better than the alternatives.

A change in k of 1 can sometimes lead to substantially different results, so you cannot just skip some values of k.

Do not just rely on measures such as Silhouette, DB, inertia, etc. to tell you what the "best" result is. These are some statistic, but that does not guarantee the result is the most useful. They can be helpful to choose candidates to explore, though.